# How to Change File format from json to KML?

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have file in `json` format of world-countries I want to change it to `KML`.

Is it possible ? if yes how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language

Since KML is just XML, if you have the JSON data of the points, you can emit an XML string with it... (Concatenate and return)